# How can i get a flat list of file dependencies filtered by entry point from the compilation in webpack 5

Tags: javascript, node.js, svg, webpack, webpack-plugin

I'm trying to update the [`svg-chunk-webpack-plugin`](https://github.com/yoriiis/svg-chunk-webpack-plugin) from webpack v4 to v5. The plugin used the [compilation](https://webpack.js.org/api/compilation-object) object and needs a flat list of file dependencies filtered by entry point to extract all SVGs for each entry points.

Example of a nested dependency tree with an entry point `app-a`

```
- app-a.js
    - svg1.svg
    - module1.js
        - svg2.svg
        - svg3.svg
        - module2.js
            - svg4.svg
            - svg5.svg
```

With **webpack `v4`**, the following code works and returns an array of all SVG files used by each entry points

```js
const path = require('path');

function getSvgsDependenciesByEntrypoint(entryName) {
    let listSvgs = [];

    compilation.entrypoints.get(entryName).chunks.forEach((chunk) => {
        chunk.getModules().forEach((module) => {
            module.buildInfo &&
                module.buildInfo.fileDependencies &&
                module.buildInfo.fileDependencies.forEach((filepath) => {
                    const extension = path.extname(filepath).substr(1);
                    if (extension === 'svg') {
                        listSvgs.push(filepath);
                    }
                });
        });
    });
    return listSvgs;
}

const svgs = getSvgsDependenciesByEntrypoint('app-a');
console.log(svgs) // ["svg1.svg", "svg2.svg", "svg3.svg", "svg4.svg", "svg5.svg"]
```

With **webpack `v5`**, I've tried the following code which produce different results between development and production build.

```js
const path = require('path');

function getSvgsDependenciesByEntrypoint(entryName) {
    let listSvgsDependencies = [];

    compilation.entrypoints.get(entryName).chunks.forEach((chunk) => {
        compilation.chunkGraph.getChunkModules(chunk).forEach((module) => {
            module.dependencies.forEach((dependency) => {
                const extension = path.extname(dependency.userRequest).substr(1);
                if (extension === 'svg') {
                    const moduleDependency = compilation.moduleGraph.getModule(dependency);
                    listSvgsDependencies.push(moduleDependency);
                }
            });
        });
    });

    return listSvgsDependencies;
}
```

In development build

```js
const svgs = getSvgsDependenciesByEntrypoint('app-a');
console.log(svgs) // ["svg1.svg", "svg2.svg", "svg3.svg", "svg4.svg", "svg5.svg"]
```

In production build

```js
const svgs = getSvgsDependenciesByEntrypoint('app-a');
console.log(svgs) // ["svg1.svg"]
```

Nested dependencies are not find with the production build

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed the bug with the webpack team on issue [#12202](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/12202#issuecomment-745537821).

This behavior is related to the side effects of the module. The webpack release [v5.10.3](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/releases/tag/v5.10.3) includes a fix which allows to manually specify the module has side effects. You could do that either in module rules or within the loader directly.